# Regulation of a switching DC/DC converter for battery charging

Tags: battery-charging, boost

I need to charge an 8 cell battery (8 21700 Li-Ion cells in series, voltage of 21.6 to 33.6V) from a 5 to 9V source with an input current of 3A max (USB PD).

This is a circuit for a boost converter with input from 5 to 9V and output of 34V, 1A. I assume D1 protects against reverse current flow when the output voltage drops below the battery voltage?

[image: Boost circuit]

My first idea was to add an 8-bit digital potentiometer to the feedback circuitry, but this results in a worst-case input current resolution of 1.5A.

- Res. of Vin: (33.6V-21.6V)/256 ≈ 50mV
- Res. of Iout (30mΩ Rᵢₙₜ per cell): 50mV/(8*30mΩ) ≈ 200mA
- Res. of input power (90% eff.): (34V*200mA)/0.90 ≈ 7.6W
- Res. of input current at 5V Vin: 7.6W/5V ≈ 1.5A

I assume it would be very hard to regulate this to get a constant input current of 500mA for example when hooked up to a standard USB 2.0 port.

A possible solution I thought of was to replace the feedback resistors with an output current shunt and some kind of amplifier. The reference voltage of the [LM3478](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf) is 1.26 V, so I'd need a circuit that amplifies the shunt's voltage - at anywhere from 2A down to something like 100mA - to 1.26V, selectable with a digital potentiometer. 256 steps between an output current of 0 to 2A equates to a worst-case input current resolution of ~60mA. There would also need to be an option to switch to constant voltage when the maximum cell voltage is reached.

Is this a viable solution or would you recommend something entirely different? I'm essentially just looking for an efficient, fairly low cost, and digitally controllable way to charge an 8 cell battery pack from an input anywhere from 5V, 500mA up to 9V, 3A.

I know I need a way to keep the cells balanced but that's not part of this question.

Comment: First, the diode is far more than reverse current protection, it's fundamental to a boost conv. Second, current control in this cct is via Rsense/Isense. (But note it's switch current, you have to scale it to control output current.)

Comment: @user_1818839 I know the diode is required for the boost topology, I was just making sure it will also act as protection against reverse current flow from the battery but I guess that question is quite redundant because of course it will. I assumed I'd need to control the output current using the FB pin, not a lot of information is provided about the Isense pin in the datasheet.